# Clarify the meaning of this custom Formfields react Hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Can somebody clarify the essence of this Hook to me? I understand the general idea and what it does but can't seem to grasp how all exactly works:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export function useFormFields(initialState) {
    const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState)

    return [
        fields,
        function(event) {
            setValues({
                ...fields,
                [event.target.id] : event.target.value
            })
        }
    ]
}
```

especially the return is most confusing to me. I would very much like to get a deeper understanding.

Comment: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-custom-react-hook-to-handle-form-fields.html

Comment: yeah thats what i am doing right now.. :) .. but still i do not understand entirely how we are handling the data...